# How can you add multiple values into a single key in a dictionary without it having commas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

In a question I asked a while ago, I got to try PyInquirer to edit multiple lines of a .txt file at once. I tried fiddling with it, when I found a problem.

This is the code:

```
question = [
    {
        'type': 'input',
        'name': 'text_lines',
        'message': '',
        'default': ('This is a test line\n' 'This is another test line\n')
    }
]

answer = prompt(question)
print('The file says:\n {}'.format(answer['text_line']))
```

As you can see, the key `'default'` used parentheses but there are no commas between the strings. When I put commas between them, the error `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting` occurs. How can I put two strings with the same key??? It was confusing to me because even the usage of square and curly brackets don't work.

I just want to recreate the `'default'` key above without commas

Edit: I didn't realize it was just concatenation. Thanks for your answers!!

Comment: `default` is not using a tuple. That is just string concatenation.

Comment: "How to solve" depends on what you're trying to do.  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what you're trying to achieve.  Python syntax uses commas to separate values in a sequence, so "two strings without a comma" is a contradiction within the language.  Make sure that your terms are accurate: In that last dict element, `'default'` is the `key`; the stuff after the colon is the `value`.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no commas, that is *not* a tuple: it's an expression evaluation, and the expression is the concatenation of two strings.  Try it in interactive mode:

```
>>> ('This is a test line\n' 'This is another test line\n')
'This is a test line\nThis is another test line\n'
```